# How to remove a populace from an array list given only its string

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public void addPopulace()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter size");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter X-Coordinate"); 
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Y-Coordinate"); 
    int y = sc.nextInt();
    Populace p = new Populace(name, size, x, y ); 
    list.add(p);
}

public void removePopulace()
{
    Scanner rmv = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter populace name to be removed"); 
    String rmvName = rmv.next();
    Populace p = new Populace(rmvName); 
    list.remove(p);
}
```

The first method prompts the user to enter a populace and their desired characteristics and adds it to an arraylist. How do I get the second method to remove a populace by simply prompting the iser only by the name of the populace. The populace is currently formatted as such:
Populace populace size x y

Comment: Java 8: `list.removeIf(p -> p.getName().equals(nameToRemove));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in your `Populace` class so that when you call `list.remove()`, the object will be removed.

Basically, your `equals()` method should provide the logic on **how two `Populace` objects are equal** (like by their `name` or `size`).

```
public class Populace {

    //add your existing code here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        //provide logic on how two objects are equal, check name, size, etc..
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //return hashcode
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use Lombok project to automate this, so you don't have to implement this in every pojo you make: https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html

Comment: @PeterAdrian Thanks for the link, but I don't recommend a third party annotation to auto generate `equals()` for a new developer because they need to understand the concept first by writing few on their own

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
for (Populace p: list)
    if (rmvName.equals(p.getName())) {
        list.remove(p);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to structure that with a while loop?

Comment: @RehanBari of course

Comment: How would that look like?

Comment: @RehanBari something like `Iterator<Populace> i = list.iterator();
       while (i.hasNext()) {
           Populace s = i.next();
           ...
       }`

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
list.removeIf(p -> p.getName().equals(rmvName));
```